# Anti-Aliasing on Path after scaling on canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have an application that draws some shapes on the screen. The Problem is that antialiasing is not working on shapes which I draw using Path, but only after scaling(zooming). 
On the other side there is no problems with drawing circles (even after scaling). The zooming works fine, just the shapes are not sharp afterwards.

```
...
// Matrix m = new Matrix();
// m.setValues(createMatrix());
// canvas.concat(m);
//or
canvas.scale(6.0f, 6.0f); // the upper code is used on real, but the same problem occures with this call
...
RectF oval = new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height);
currentPaint.setAntiAlias( true );
canvas.drawOval(oval, currentPaint);

currentPaint.setAntiAlias( true );
canvas.drawPath(getPathOfShape(), currentPaint);
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. The problem was that this was not supproted from android if the hardware accelaration was enabled. After disabling the hardware accelaration the scaling was working fine.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

For more information about this, see the google site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html